# Javaで日付文字列をparse出来ない

Tags: android, java

下記のコードを走らせると
`W/System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Mar 29 18:17:17 GMT+09:00 2018"`
となり、エラーになってしまいます。

どうすべきか、教えていただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
SimpleDateFormat sdFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss");
Date getDate = sdFormat.parse("Thu Mar 29 18:17:17 GMT+09:00 2018");
```

Comment: パースしようとしている日付文字列は明らかに`"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss"`という書式にはなっていないようですが、なぜその書式文字列でパースしようとしているのですか?

Comment: データベースから読み出したデータを文字列にしたときに`Thu Mar 29 18:17:17 GMT+09:00 2018`となっており、それをまたデータベースに戻そうと考えていますが、StringからDate型に変換する過程でパースしようとしています。

Comment: そもそもデータベースから呼び出した日付を文字列にする際にきちんと`SimpleDateFormat`を使用すべきところだろうと思います。また`"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss"`という書式は`"2018/03/29 06:17:17"`のような文字列にマッチします。`"Thu Mar 29 18:17:17 GMT+09:00 2018"`には全く当てはまらないですよね。このような日付文字列を読み取りたい場合の書式文字列について尋ねたい、と解釈してよろしいのでしょうか?

Comment: ありがとうございます。その通りです。日付型ならある程度何でも変換できる訳ではないのですね。

Comment: 使う言語やライブラリによっては、どんな書式を指定しても大抵の日付文字列が読める、なんて場合があるかも知れませんが、Javaの`SimpleDateFormat`の場合は、そんな動きはしてくれないです。日付の処理は結構面倒で、似たような機能があっても細かい動作が異なることがあるので、少し調べて(例えば`SimpleDateFormat`なら[こちら](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/6/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)みられることをお勧めします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

読み込むデータが全て同じフォーマットならば、それに合うように`SimpleDateFormat()`の引数を変えればいいはずです。

```
SimpleDateFormat sdFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzzzzzz yyyy");
Date date = sdFormat.parse("Thu Mar 29 18:17:17 GMT+09:00 2018", new ParsePosition(0));
System.out.println(date.toString());
```

Output:

```
Thu Mar 29 09:17:17 GMT 2018
```

Comment: `hh`は`HH`にすべきだろうと思います。

Comment: @OOPer  あ、すみません、その通りです。修正しました。（もしかすると`kk`の可能性も?）

Comment: ありがとうございます。ご指摘の方法で解決しました。

Comment: @packet0 さん、修正どうもです。`kk`については、可能性としては0ではないですが、「特殊な書式を意図的に指定した」なんて話がない限り、非常に低い可能性でしかないかと思います。